# sessionCookiePath attribute doesn't work on my tomcat7 server

Tags: java, session, tomcat, cookies, config

I deployed two web applications on my tomcat server, i hope they can share session data between each other. so i add an attribute sessionCookiePath="/" into the Context tag in context.xml file. but after restart the server, it still set the cookie with application path, such as "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7200fce5-8aee-4d95-b4d8-4ab586dba152; Path=/webapp1; HttpOnly"!

The version of tomcat server is 7.047.

Here's the content of my context.xml

```
<Context sessionCookiePath="/"><WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource></Context>
```

And here's server.xml

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"><Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
```

After that, i tried to fix this problem with web.xml in the applicatoin, added cookie-config tag, but it still doesn't work.

this is web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>imeapcore</display-name><session-config>
<cookie-config>
    <path>/</path>
</cookie-config></session-config>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>nutz</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.nutz.mvc.NutFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>modules</param-name>
        <param-value>com.imeap.webservice.MainModule</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>nutz</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I used shiro manage session info instead of tomcat itself, so "sessionCookiePath" attribute was omitted. This should be set in shiro.ini, such as:

```
sessionIdCookie=org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
sessionIdCookie.name=sid  
sessionIdCookie.path=/
```